# need help to cut a string with PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string:

```
$str = "http://www.abc.com/xxx/xxx/v54/c505/1.html";
```

How do I cut the trailing `1.html` off ?

The result I desire is `http://www.abc.com/xxx/xxx/v54/c505/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

```
$newStr = dirname($str) . '/';
```

Comment: @alex I tested before answering ;-)

Comment: I double checked for you before dispensing the +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '/') + 1);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/hfBnSJAd).

Comment: +1 Good for removing the last portion of an arbitrarily delimited string

Answer (score 0):

You can use dirname() --

```
$str = "http://www.abc.com/xxx/xxx/v54/c505/1.html";
$dir = dirname($str);
```